# After upgrading mongoose 5.x my application become very slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose

To update my value in nested array , I have upgrade my mongoose 4.13.2 to 5.2.6 after upgrading .count is not working . So I read document

```
mongo.inspection.update({"projectID" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.project_id) },
{ "$set": {

    "inspection_data.$[e1].locationAspects.$[e2].comments.$[e3].images.$[e4].title" : "TableFan"
  }},
  { "arrayFilters": [
    { "e1._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.insId)},
    { "e2._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.aspectId)},
    { "e3._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.commentId)},
    { "e4.id": "1" } 
  ]},function(err,response){
      if(err){
          console.log("error")
      }
      else{
          console.log('Updated')
          console.log(response)
      }
    })
```

db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )

After upgrading my application is very slow. How do I resolve this?

Comment: ***.count is not working*** where?

Comment: I have fixed that issue.. Now performance is slow